# Definição de método não genérico?

Tags: c#, .net, orientação-a-objetos, genéricos, extension-method

Em

```
public partial class frmAltInfo : Form
```

Ocorre o erro:

> Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

Não entendo o que pode ser e nem como resolver.

Aqui estava o erro:

```
public static string TextNoFormatting(this MaskedTextBox _mask)

{
  _mask.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
    String retString = _mask.Text;
    _mask.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludePromptAndLiterals;
    return retString;
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código e o erro separado ao invés da tela. Desta forma fica difícil achar sua pergunta em buscadores.

Comment: Além do this.Close, em nenhuma outra parte tem um parâmetro com this. 

Devo colocar o código todo na pergunta?

Comment: O ideal é colocar só o que está te afetando mas se não souber bem onde está, seria melhor. Veja que a classe é parcial portanto tem outra parte dela em algum lugar.

Comment: Acontece que todas as outras classes são exatamente iguais a essa, porém, não ocorre este erro. Estou me matando o dia todo para conseguir arrumar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O erro não está neste trecho; está em outra parte. Você deve ter definido um método de extensão dentro desta classe e você não pode definir assim por ela não ser estática. Como este trecho deixa claro que a classe não pode ser estática o problema está no método definido. Ache ele. Ele tem um parâmetro com `this`.

Como a classe é `partial` deve ter uma outra parte dela em outro arquivo. O trecho que dá problema pode estar neste outro arquivo.

Se você realmente precisa deste método como extensão deve criar uma classe estática separada para ele.

Outra solução é tornar este método normal e não de extensão retirando o modificador do primeiro parâmetro `this`. Ficaria assim:

```
public static string TextNoFormatting(MaskedTextBox _mask) {
    _mask.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.ExcludePromptAndLiterals;
    String retString = _mask.Text;
    _mask.TextMaskFormat = MaskFormat.IncludePromptAndLiterals;
    return retString;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/StaticMethodExample.cs).

A simples retirada do `this`antes do parâmetro `_mask` resolve o problema.

Como *sidenote* essa nomenclatura de variável é fora de padrão. Não existe nnhum motivo para usar o sublinhado.

[Documentação sobre métodos de extensão](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Somente métodos de extensão têm restrição na maneira como a classe deve ser definida. Métodos estáticos normais podem estar em qualquer classe. A questão só é se ele deve estar na classe, o que ele vai fazer, acessar.

Comment: Ah cara, achei o erro, muito obrigado!

Comment: Uma outra dúvida, como deve ser a classe para aceitar um método static?

Comment: Se for só `static` não tem muita restrição de como a classe deve ser. Mas pense bem se a classe realmente precisa de um membro estático, na maioria das vezes se a classe não for utilitária (fazer tarefas isoladas) métodos estáticos são pouco necessários. E no caso este método seria utilitário também.

Comment: Neste caso precisa, pois é para fazer algo especifico. Agradeço muito a sua ajuda.

Comment: Era isso mesmo! Que mensagem de erro lixo ¬¬

Comment: @SérgioS.Filho eu acho ela boa